# My Background Doesn't show in Internet Explorer (CSS)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been sitting here for about minutes trying to figure out why my css background is not showing up on my wordpress blog. All of the other css code works in the style sheet. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is the code.

```
body {
    background-image:url('http:/www.itsnotch.com/images/itsnotchbg.jpg');
        background-color: #000;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:top center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

It shows up in all other browsers EXCEPT internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The url to the background image is wrong: it's missing a / after http:

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a / in your URL. It should be

```
background-image:url('http://www.itsnotch.com/images/itsnotchbg.jpg');
```

and not

```
background-image:url('http:/www.itsnotch.com/images/itsnotchbg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've declared a background-color and a background-image . You need to choose one. By default browsers use the last declaration. So in this case it would be your background-color showing and not your image.

Are you just seeing a black background for this?

Comment: Not true ... you can define both a background image and a background color. The background image will display above, and if you don't repeat in one or both directions, that background color will fill out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
background-image: url(http://www.itsnotch.com/images/itsnotchbg.jpg);
```